# Enforce typing on string keys/IDs

Tags: oop, types, reuseidentifier

In a generic OO language (say C++, C#, java)
I have a map of objects with a string ID and the same ID is also key of the relative object

```
class Foo(){
    Foo(string id){this.id = id;}
    string id;
    string otherProperty;
}
map<string,Foo> foos;
```

now if i want to add an object i'd

```
map.add("myFirstID", new Foo("myFirstID"));
map.add("mySecondID", new Foo("mySecondID"));
```

I don't like to repeat strings, it will just get worst ( think to when retrieving by key it just explode ).

I can't use an enum (since in some languages like c++ it can't be easily converted to string, and i need it)

only option seems to be a cascade of

```
const string MY_FIRST_ID = "myFirstID";
const string MY_SECOND_ID = "mySecondID";
```

to then

```
foos.add(MY_FIRST_ID, new Foo(MY_FIRST_ID));
```

This solutions is better, still it's very verbose, there's still some coupling in same class and there's no enforcing on the values ( like there's for an enum );

Can you think any better pattern?

PS: another solution is to only use enum as keys and put the string as a simple field. But this require to add high coupling between Foo and FooManager ( class instantiating foo instances )

Answer (score 0):

You could always do your

```
var f = new Foo("myFirstID")
```

and then do a

```
map.add(f.id, f);
```

Another thing to explore is, if need to have that key just to provide uniqueness of the object foo, explore the hashset collection, available in both c# and java world. If you provide a IEqualityComparer you can just add and delete you foo objects. This can be a solution if you don't need to access your hashset with the string acessor.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can do something like:

```
string foo;
map.add(foo = "myFirstID", new Foo(foo));
```

I'm not sure if you can do the same in Java or in C++ but it is a good staring point.

Comment: thank you but the problem is just delayed to the first required map.get("myFirstID");
moreover no uiniqueness is provided nor enforce on the provided values .